Proof of the equivalence of spectra $(\mathbb{S}^{-1} \otimes \mathbb{S}^{-1})_{h \Sigma_2} \cong \Sigma^{-1} \mathbb{RP}_{-1}^{\infty}$
$\DeclareMathOperator{\colim}{colim}$$\DeclareMathOperator{\Th}{Th}$I am trying to give a hands-on proof of the equivalence of spectra in the title. I am using the definitions $\mathbb{RP}^{\infty}_{-1} := \colim_k \mathbb{RP}_{-1}^{k}$  and $\mathbb{RP}_{-1}^{k} := \Th(- \mathbb{L}, \mathbb{RP}^{k+1})$ where $\mathbb{L}$ denotes the canonical line bundle on $\mathbb{RP}^{k+1}$. Moreover, if $E$ is a vector bundle over a compact Hausdorff base $B$, then I use the definition $\Th(-E,B) := \Sigma^{-n} \mathrm{Th}(E', B)$, where $E'$ is a vector bundle over $B$ such that $E \oplus E'$ is trivial of rank $n$. Such a complementary bundle exists by Proposition 1.4 in Hatcher's book on K-theory for example.
In the case of the canonical line bundle on $\mathbb{RP}^{k}$,
I think we can find explicit complements as follows. I read (see Adams' paper on vector fields on spheres for example) that the virtual bundle $\mathbb{L} -1$ generates $\widetilde{\text{KO}}(\mathbb{RP}^k) \cong \mathbb{Z}/2^{f_k} \mathbb{Z}$, where $f_k$ is the number of integers $i$ such that $0 < i ≤ k$ and $i ≡ 0, 1,2$ or $4\mod 8$. So $2^{f_k}(\mathbb{L} -1) = 0$ and I think the definition of $\widetilde{\text{KO}}$ now implies that $2^{f_k} \mathbb{L} + n_k \mathbb{1} \cong (2^{f_k}+n_k) \mathbb{1}$ for some $n_k \geq 0$.
My question is if we can give a proof of the equivalence $(\mathbb{S}^{-1} \otimes \mathbb{S}^{-1})_{h \Sigma_2} \cong \Sigma^{-1} \mathbb{RP}_{-1}^{\infty}$ in this setting. The fact that Thom spaces of universal bundles can be identified with representation spheres will probably be helpful (applied to the universal $\Sigma_2$-bundle $S^{\infty} \to \mathbb{RP}^{\infty}$). Somehow I keep running into trouble when trying to write down a proof.
Hopefully my question is clear enough. If you can't answer my question but know a different proof of this equivalence (perhaps in a different setting) I would also be interested in that. Thanks in advance!

This is probably not quite what you were looking for, but since you said you'd also be happy to see any proof, here is one using a modern perspective on Thom spectra of virtual bundles:
The flip action of $C_2$ on $(\mathbb{S}^n)^{\otimes 2}$ is a functor $BC_2\to Sp$ which, for nonnegative $n$, factors through the symmetric-monoidal functor $\mathrm{Vect}^{\cong} \to \mathrm{Sp}$ given by taking a vector space $V$ to the suspension spectrum on its one-point compactification $S^V$. Here $\mathrm{Vect}^{\cong}$ is the topological groupoid of real vector spaces with isomorphisms (with the usual topology on $\mathrm{GL}_n$).
The lift to vector spaces is given by the flip action on $\mathbb{R}^n\oplus\mathbb{R}^n$.
The definition of Thom spaces via fibrewise 1-point compactification tells you that the Thom spectrum of a vector bundle, encoded as functor $X\to\mathrm{Vect}^{\cong}$, is obtained by postcomposing with the functor to $\mathrm{Sp} $, and taking the colimit over $X$. For $X=BC_2$, this colimit has another name: it's the homotopy orbits, giving you the equivalence
$$
\mathrm{Th}(BC_2,\mathbb{R}^n\oplus\mathbb{R}^n) \simeq ((\mathbb{S}^n)^{\otimes 2})_{hC_2}
$$
for nonnegative $n$.
What happens for negative $n$? The crucial fact is that the symmetric-monoidal functor
$\mathrm{Vect}^{\cong} \to \mathrm{Sp}$
factors through the group completion of the left hand side, since it takes values in invertible objects on the right. This group completion can be identified with $BO\times\mathbb{Z}$, but we don't need that here. Even if we just call it $G$, we get that we still have Thom spectra for maps $X\to G$ (as colimit), and that for any such map $X\to G$ which arises as formal difference of an actual vector bundle and a trivial vector bundle, the Thom spectrum is a desuspension. Now $G$ contains a point/object "$\mathbb{R}^{-1}$", and from the symmetric-monoidal structure a map $BC_2\to G$ encoding "the flip action on $(\mathbb{R}^{-1})^{\oplus 2}$". This has Thom spectrum given by $(\mathbb{S}^{-1})^{\otimes 2}_{hC_2}$ as before, but the map $BC_2\to G$ is also the negative of the actual vector bundle we get for $\mathbb{R}^1$. In the $n=1$ case we are dealing with the vector bundle corresponding to the regular representation of $C_2$, which splits into a trivial and a sign representation. So the vector bundle splits as $1\oplus L$. The Thom spectrum we found for $n=-1$ is thus $\mathrm{Th}(BC_2,-1-L)$. The equivalence
$$
\mathrm{Th}(BC_2,-1-L)\simeq (\mathbb{S}^{-1})^{\otimes 2}_{hC_2}
$$
is a shift of the one we were looking to prove.
By definition as a colimit the left hand side can also be written a colimit over skeleta of $BC_2$, as
$$
\mathrm{colim}_k \mathrm{Th}(\mathbb{R}P^k,-1-L), 
$$
and on each of those a complement to $L$ allows you to express the Thom spectrum as an actual desuspension, relating it to the hands-on construction. The advantage is that you don't have to produce compatible maps for those by hand, they come out of the direct description of the Thom spectrum.
